# How can I call a function in C++ dll that returns a pointer to a list in C#

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I am new to C# and I am trying to transfer a C++ package into a WPF project. Since I didn't want to rewrite all the codes in C#, I created a C++ dll and encapsulated all the functions I would call in WPF in this dll. However, some functions use (either as input parameter or as return type) a list of some Node I have define, e.g. `List<myNode>* list`, where myNode stores some integer and double values and has reference to its previous and next node. List is defined as follows:

```
template<class N>
class List {
public:
    int id;
    double value;
    N* first;
    N* last;
    int numOfNodes;
    List* before;
    List* next;
}
```

I tried defining `myNode` in C# and directly calling this function with `List<myNode>` in C# but it throws an `System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException` with the error message "Generic type cannot be marshaled.". How can I properly call these functions in C#?

For reference, let's say the functions I am trying to transfer are `List<myNode>* buildList(int a, double b)` and `int readToList(std:string path, List<myNode>* list)`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your dll C++ or C++/CLI? If it's plain C++ consider making a C++/CLI dll with some wrapper functions that handle the interop.

Comment: It's a plain C++ dll. Can you elaborate a bit more on how to do this or can you point me to the right online resource for doing this? Thank you.

Comment: Is the list in c++ a class or a structure?  If c++ is using a structure than use a structure in c# not a class.

Comment: It's a C++ class

Comment: @jdweng: That's a meaningless question.  In C++, the `class` keyword and the `struct` keyword both create classes.

Comment: C++ data structure containing pointers do not play well with p/invoke.  You've just hit the first of a great many difficulties, most of which will be related to "Who allocates, the memory, who is responsible for freeing it, and when?"  For one thing, C# doesn't know how to call C++ destructors.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for the reply. Do you know any resources that have information about how this can be done or do you think that instead of handling this from C++ side, I should just rewrite the codes in C#? Thanks.